# HttpResponse can return list in android through RESTFUL web service?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, rest

I am new to android.i am using Restful web Services.I have one field like Category in mySql Database.now I need to get value from database and put it into AutoCompleteTextView.but I can get values from database.and also I know how to set that value into AutoCompleteTextView.but I don't know how can I get list from HttpResponse. HttpResponse can return list?

Comment: @Eric Stein:can you give the answer for my question?

Comment: Welcome to the internet. Sadly, you are not in charge. I downvoted your question because (a) using bold is obnoxious, (b) not learning from the last 8 posts getting corrected to not use bold is willfully obnoxious, and (c) your question is poor. Ask a specific question, get a specific answer. Right now, the only reasonable answer to your question is "yes". This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be returning an `HttpResponse` from your REST service.  Return a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` instead.  Then you can insert any data entity you like into the response like this:

```
// method annotation here
public Response someGetMethod() {
    // build listFromDatabase here
    return Response.ok(listFromDatabase).build();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your Answer friend.but i know how to pass value at server side.but i need to set in client side :(

Comment: You should probably update your question to reflect that.  Try rewording your question to make it clear that you are having a problem on the client side, and include the client code giving you problems.

Comment: oh sorry friend.i am new to stack overflow that's the reason i putted wrongly.